# Объявление переменной SQL в php

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть код

```
for ($i=0; $i < $images ; $i++) { 
    $zapros = 'SELECT images.img, objects.object_type, objects.location, objects.floor, objects.numberRooms, objects.livingArea, objects.kitchenArea,objects.landArea,objects.roomCondition,objects.commission,objects.cost 
               FROM objects 
               INNER JOIN images 
               ON objects.id_obj=1 = images.id_objects=1';

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$zapros);
    $catalog = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

}
```

В переменной `zapros` производится запрос данных с 2 таблиц. Обратите внимание на концовку запроса после `ON`. Там происходит вывод данных с таблицы `objects` где `id_obj=1` и сравнивается с данными из таблицы `images` с данными которые подходят под критерий `id_objects=1`

**Перейдём к самой сути**

Можно ли подставить динамическую переменную в место `id_obj=динамическаяПеременная` и `id_objects=динамическаяПеременная`, чтобы при каждом проходе цикла эта переменная увеличивалась на 1

Мне не важно будет ли это php или sql переменная. Главное, чтобы она работала.

Comment: `objects.id_obj=1 = images.id_objects=1` --- вместо `=` должно быть `AND` ?

Comment: "Можно ли подставить динамическую переменную" --- можно. У вас как минимум эта переменная `$i`. Однако вряд ли кто-то из присутствующих понимает зачем это нужно, потому что это не имеет никакого смысла. Да ещё и делать это в цикле

Comment: Если там будет динамическая переменная, то я буду поэтапно получать необходимые мне данные которые будут очерёдно стоять под 1,2,3,4,....1000 номером. При получении их поэтапно мне будет удобнее реализовать их "распихивание" туда где им место. Сейчас же без этой переменной я получаю очень много данных и не могу с ними работать(

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, покалдую над этим)

Comment: Алексей, извините за беспокойство. Не могли бы вы прописать этот момент:
objects.id_obj=1 = images.id_objects=1 --- вместо = должно быть AND ? – чуть конкретнее. Как не ошибиться и присвоить к ним $i?

Comment: Самое лучшее это сделать нормальный запрос. Цикл убрать, а в запросе должно быть что-то типа такого: `.......... INNER JOIN images 
               ON objects.id_obj = images.id_objects  WHERE objects.id_obj IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10......N)` - где значения в IN просто формируются одной строкой. Больше тут ничего не надо

Comment: А если объектов вдруг будет миллион а картинок и вовсе в 10 раз больше?

Comment: LEFT JOIN, а не INNER JOIN - это раз........... Объекты выбираются порцией (есть такая штука как пагинация для этого), а не сразу все, иначе у вас сервак умрёт.  - это два.............  Ну и если в цикле перебирать миллион запросов - то это как раз в миллион раз затратнее чем одним запросом выбрать - это три.